# Creating Dell factory backup will delete all other data from this drive

Tags: backup, dell-inspiron

I'd like to create a factory backup disk to the Dell laptop that I recently aquired.
I want to save this factory backup on an external WD flash drive (that has 500GB). 
This disk contains, already 100GB of other personal data.

**My question is:** will the process of creating factory disk **delete all** other data on that drive (I don't want that to happend of course) or it will create the Image disk in addition to the other data the in this disk?? 
Dell's wizard said that the factory data requires only 9.2GB so there's plenty of space for all the data together.

Comment: Normally factory backups (or recovery disks) are written to DVDs. That is the case at least for my Sony laptop.

Comment: What does the wizard say?  You should backup the data.  This all depends on the version of the software.  If the disk is going to be wiped it should indicate that.

Comment: Have you contacted Dell?

Comment: Another option to DVD is a USB Flash drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer taken from [Dell forum](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/p/19616682/20723143#20723143) where I also asked it (thanks for the advice CharlieRB):

> The answer is yes, it will delete all data from the drive.  SInce you
>   can now easily buy a 16G USB flash drive for as little as $7-10,
>   that's the way to go - you can dedicate the flash drive to the task
>   and store it in a safe place.